# configurable products or bundled products in magento

Tags: php, jquery, magento

I am working in magento

Lets say i have one product "Tshirt" and for that i have 3 sizes "Large", "Medium", "Small" and for every size of Tshirt i have 2 or 1 colors. For "large" and "medium" size i have red and green color but for small size i have only 1 color and that is "green"

I am trying to do this with configurable products or bundled products in magento. can it is possible with configurable products or bundled products? If no! how we can do this, should i have to change the value with jquery?

Thank you for Help in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use both, but in this case I think it’s better to use configurable products.

Bundle products are useful for shipping many parts (simple product) of a product in different shipments. You do not send the size and color of the shirt in different shipments.

For every product you can configure the shirt size, and the respective colors for every size.

For example:

```
shirt large -> blue, red
shirt small -> red
```

Magento will create for you many simple products; as many combinations of attributes as you select. You have only to assure that the primary configuration choice for users is placed at the first place on the attributes list, so the users can select the size before the color.

If this is not clear, ask.

You can download the Magento manual here:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/resources/user-guide-download

It is not necessary touch the jQuery code in the page.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, if it is possible in that would really help me..I will try and let you know.. Thank you for the help.